# 7z data compression utility -is missing

Tags: software-installation

How can i correct it? also CMake and autoreconf tool are missing.

```
nitc@nitc-OptiPlex-7010:~/workspace$ bake.py check
 > Python - OK
 > GNU C++ compiler - OK
 > Mercurial - OK
 > CVS - OK
 > GIT - OK
 > Bazaar - OK
 > Tar tool - OK
 > Unzip tool - OK
 > Unrar tool - OK
 > 7z  data compression utility - is missing
 > XZ data compression utility - OK
 > Make - OK
 > cMake - is missing
 > patch tool - OK
 > autoreconf tool - is missing

 > Path searched for tools: /usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm /usr/local/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/sbin /usr/bin /sbin /bin /usr/games /usr/local/games /home/nitc/workspace/bake /home/nitc/workspace/bake bin  /home/nitc/workspace/bake /home/nitc/workspace/bake
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you find yourself missing some tool you don't know where is, one way of finding it could be by using `apt-cache search`.

```
apt-cache search 7z
```

This will show you a short list where one of the entries are:

```
p7zip - 7z file archiver with high compression ratio
```

So to solve your primary question you'd run:

```
apt-get install p7zip
```

You'll get CMake and autoreconf by installing the cmake and autoconf packages:

```
apt-get install cmake autoconf
```

Answer (score 1):

Just install the missing tools:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install cmake autoconf p7zip-full
```

Or, if you are not root,

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cmake autoconf p7zip-full
```